# SUM, group by and order by make a query 700+ times slower on MySQL

Tags: mysql, performance, group-by, sql-order-by

I'm testing how fast a query will run because It'll be run often. I inserted 500 000 fake records in order to see the performance. Here's the query

```
SELECT SUM(party_size) AS sump FROM `bookings` USE INDEX(index_group_orderby) 
JOIN users ON users.id=bookings.users_id JOIN restaurants ON restaurants.id=bookings.restaurants_id 
WHERE timestamp BETWEEN '2014-02-01' AND '2014-02-09 23:59' AND users.usertype=1 
AND bookings.made_from=1 AND bookings.status=1 AND restaurants_id=4 
GROUP BY users_id ORDER BY sump
```

It runs for ~2 seconds. If I remove SUM,GROUP BY and ORDER BY it runs for 0.0025 seconds.
I'm using indexes on `users.usertype` and another ON `bookings(party_size,timestamp,status restaurants_id,users_id)`.

Here's the `explain` and what is interesting is that MySQL isn't using the `bookings` although I wrote it in the query.
[image: explain]

My question is why `group by` and `order by` make the query that much slower and why isn't MySQL using the index?

Comment: Please post `SHOW CREATE TABLE bookings`. how is the index `index_grou_orderby` defined?

Comment: Here's the index part `KEY index_group_orderby(party_size,timestamp,status,restaurants_id,users_id)`

Comment: There are many things you have to see when the query is not performing  well. As looking at your query WHERE Clause is what your query is making it slow because you are using date field.You can change the date field not time which will give some boost. Second I will look at the index as well..

Comment: @maverick it's a timestamp field

Comment: But does `users_id` have an index alone? Did you define a `FOREIGN KEY` on `users_id`? Do you get better performance if you `GROUP BY `users.id` instead of `bookings.users_id`, since `users.id` is known to be a PK?

Comment: @Michael If I use `users.id` or add an index alone on `users_id` the query runs for ~1.75 seconds. Yes, `users_id` has a foreign key

Comment: It does not matter what field it is so your WHERE Statement should be something like '2013-01-01' and '2013-03-29'.